# Converting circular structure to JSON - 3rd party API

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, axios

I'm building out a project that is making a call to a blockchain API. Unfortunately, the data I'm getting back is circular so while it works in Postman my server errors when trying to convert it to JSON. I tried using `JSON.stringify` but nothing changed.

Here's the controller function:

```
blockchainController.search = (req, res) => {
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `https://chain.api.btc.com/v3/address/${req.body.address}/tx`
  })
  .then(data => {
    res.json({
      message: 'Transactions loaded',
      data: data
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(err);
  })
};
```

Any ideas for a workaround or a fix? I'd like to be able to send this data to my front-end but it ain't happening.

Comment: How exactly do you obtain the circular data ? It can't be just by parsing some JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to use a library designed to prune circular references.

I happen to have built such library: https://github.com/Canop/JSON.prune

You can simply call it with

```
let json = JSON.prune(yourCircularObject);
```

This adds some `"-pruned-"` marks whenever a reference is ignored.

If you prefer a "silent" removal, you can do

```
let json = JSON.prune(yourCircularObject, {prunedString: undefined });
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using this and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Seems to be working for now, thanks. I tried other libraries before posting this question and either they don't work anymore or I set them up wrong.